# find by id in spring data jpa Base Repository

Tags: java, database, spring, repository, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to implement a generic `findByIdsIn` method in the `BaseRepository` of my Spring Data JPA class so that the functionality can be used by all the classes that implement that interface.
I'm pretty new to Spring Data JPA so I'm not sure if that is possible and how to implement it.

Here's the code I have so far. The `findByIdsIn` is the functionality I'd like to implement.

```
import org.springframework.data.repository.NoRepositoryBean;
import org.springframework.data.repository.Repository;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

@NoRepositoryBean
public interface BaseRepository<T, ID extends Serializable> extends Repository<T, ID> {
    List<T> findAll( );
    Optional<T> findById(ID id);
    List<T> findByIdsIn(List<ID> ids); // This is the functionality I'd like to implement.
}
```

Do you guys have any suggestions?
Many thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've just found a solution I'm satisfied with:

```
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface BaseRepository<T, ID extends Serializable> extends Repository<T, ID> {
    List<T> findAll( );
    Optional<T> findById(ID id);
    @Query("SELECT t FROM #{#entityName} t WHERE t.id IN :ids")
    List<T> findByIdsIn(@Param("ids") List<ID> ids);
}
```

I'm happy for other people to contribute if there are more elegant solutions, though.

Comment: wouldn't it require registering the BaseRepository with JPA?

Comment: @jimmy can you please accept answer to this question.

Answer (score 0):

By default, `SimpleJpaRepository` is the implementations for basic repository operations. You should implement and write a class extending `SimpleJpaRepository`. As generic types to this implementation pass two types of parameter as passed in the interface `SimpleJpaRepository`. Below is a sample implementation of your requirement:

```
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Optional;

public class BaseRepositoryImpl <T, ID extends Serializable>
        extends SimpleJpaRepository<T, ID>  implements BaseRepository<T, ID> {

    private final EntityManager entityManager;

    public BaseRepositoryImpl(Class<T> domainClass, EntityManager entityManager) {
        super(domainClass, entityManager);
        this.entityManager = entityManager;
    }

    @Override
   public  List<T> findByIdsIn(List<ID> ids) {
        List<T> entities = entityManager.createQuery(
        "FROM"+this.getDomainClass()+" WHERE id IN ("+CommonUtils.concat(ids,',')+")").getResultList(); // concatenation code is not tested hence u need to fix it 
        return entities;
    }
}
```

Also, you will need to override default implementation i.e. 
 `SimpleJpaRepository` with your implementation i.e. `BaseRepositoryImpl`

```
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.data.repository.core.RepositoryMetadata;
import org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import java.io.Serializable;

public class BaseRepositoryFactoryBean<R extends JpaRepository<T, I>, T,
        I extends Serializable> extends JpaRepositoryFactoryBean<R, T, I> {

    @Override
    protected RepositoryFactorySupport createRepositoryFactory(EntityManager entityManager) {
        return new BaseRepositoryFactory(entityManager);
    }

    private static class BaseRepositoryFactory<T, I extends Serializable>
            extends JpaRepositoryFactory {

        private final EntityManager entityManager;

        public BaseRepositoryFactory(EntityManager entityManager) {
            super(entityManager);
            this.entityManager = entityManager;
        }

        @Override
        protected Object getTargetRepository(RepositoryMetadata metadata) {
            return new BaseRepositoryImpl<T, I>((Class<T>) metadata.getDomainType(), entityManager);
        }

        @Override
        protected Class<?> getRepositoryBaseClass(RepositoryMetadata metadata) {
            return BaseRepositoryImpl.class;
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, configure your `BaseRepositoryFactoryBean` in Spring configuration by using `@EnableJpaRepositories` annotation and specifying your class as below. This will tell JPA which RepositoryFactoryBean to call and which in turn tell which JPA repository to use throughout and initialize it with its implementation using its Impl class.

```
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"com.test.jpa.custom.repository"},
        repositoryFactoryBeanClass = BaseRepositoryFactoryBean.class)
class Configuration{}
```

Now you could use `BaseRepository` and `findByIdsIn` will be available for usage throughout your application.

Comment: I have tried to put sufficient code to help you create a custom repository. But there should be some useful links too that explain in detail why you needed so many steps

Comment: whoever downvoted, can you please help me understand the issue with this post.